# The app module disappear in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have opened up my project, and have noticed that the default module (app) has disappeared. I am not sure how to add it back since it has shown that it doesn't exist.

This this the error that I am getting for my project.

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MQsmartAccess'
```

This is what the project currently looks like.

[image]

When I click on edit configuration, It will say that there are no modules.

This is my gradle build:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
 sub-projects/modules.
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
  task delete(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies{
implementation project(':app')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

How can i fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Open your **buil.gradle** file change something to sync project. That might be 
        **versionName "1.1.1"** after syncing successfully go back to your previous versionName. Hope it will solve your problem. Although this is a ridiculous solution. I have faced that issue several times. And solve using this way.

Comment: Nope that didn't work :( I mean there was a module (app) there (app), but when I re-opened the project it was gone. @Al-Amin

Answer (score -1):

I found it in the `src` folder. It is with the name `build.gradle`. The content are the same as `build.gradle(Module app)`. In case you don't find it there. I deleted everything from the `.gitignore` first. I am not sure I got the file because of deleting the `.gitignore` file.